# how we check if a dll is compatible with a specific language

Tags: php, dll

I load an API into dll file from a software coding in C# to my web app in PHP.

- I follow the install process with the extension everything seems ok
  but my dll doesn't appear in my phpinfo().
- Into my PHP ERROR LOG i've got this : `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:Unable to load dynamic library

     'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_theapi.dll'`

I would like to know how we check if the dll is **compatible** with PHP. 
And in Second time someone can post a method for get the entry point for the dll.

PS: I have IIS istalled and i am on MS server R8

#### Someone get a idea ?